# Is the set of all infinite sequences vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ consist of all sequences $\{a_n\}$ in field $F$ that have only a finite number of nonzero terms $a_n$. If $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ are in $V$ and $t \in F$, define $\{a_n\}+\{b_n\}=\{a_n+b_n\}$ and $t\{a_n\}=\{ta_n\}$. With these operations $V$ is a vector space

Why *finite number of nonzero terms* is required ?

Comment: It isn't. It's a vector space if there are only finitely many nonzero terms, and it's a (different) vector space if there's no such restriction.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Do you mean regardless of the restriction, V is a vector space? (but different vector space). If so, the set of all infinite sequences is also (different) vector space so the answer of my question is Yes. Is it right?

Comment: The answer to the question in the title (as opposed to the question in the body) is Yes.

Comment: The reason for having only finitely many nonzero terms is just that you will then be able to exhibit a basis (and that this vector space is isomorphic to the vector space of polynomials in one variable). If you consider **all** sequences you *also* get a vector space, but one for which a basis cannot be explicitly exhibited.  There are two vector spaces, one contained in the other: the one you have is the smaller one, the one without the restriction is a *larger* vector space that contains $V$ as a subspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summing up the comments, if $W$ is the vector space consisting of all sequences $\{a_n\}$ in a field $F$, then $W$ is a vector space, and $V$ would be a subspace of $W$. The key thing to note is that although $V$ and $W$ are both vector spaces, they are distinct vector spaces.

Some key differences between $V$ and $W$: for $V$ it's really easy to find a basis. For instance, the set of sequences $\{\{a_i=0\,\forall\,i\neq k,a_k=1\}:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a basis of $V$ but not a basis of $W$ (e.g $a = (1,1,1,\ldots)$ is an example of something in $W$ that cannot be written as a finite combination of vectors from the 'basis'). This simplicity helps with proofs.

In general, just a word of warning for reading mathematics: just because an author does things a certain way doesn't mean that that way is *required*. It's possible that it works in a more general case, and that the author is making the argument simpler and more concrete and easier to understand. Critiquing things in general is good, but just because it's done doesn't necessarily mean it's necessary :)